# Under weak convergence, is the limit's moment infinite if the sequence's moments are infinite?

Tags: probability-theory

If a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges in distribution to some r.v. $X$, the convergence of moments doesn't immediately follow. However, if the sequence is uniformly integrable, then we have the convergence of moments.

Thus, for example, if $X_n\Rightarrow X$ and $\sup \mathbb{E}[|X_n|^{1+\varepsilon}]<\infty$ for some $\varepsilon >0$ (a sufficient condition for uniform integrability), then $\mathbb{E}[|X|]<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]→\mathbb{E}[X]$. (See for example Theorem 25.12 and Corollary in Billingsley's Probability and Measure).

My situation however is this: $X_n\Rightarrow X$, and $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\infty$.

QUESTION: Does it follow that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\infty$ too?

Let me add that all the $X_n$ and $X$ are nonnegative so their moments are defined ($\mathbb{R}_+ \cup \infty$).

The moment convergence results I've seen all invoke uniform integrability and finiteness of moments, which doesn't apply here. Is it even possible to have $\mathbb{E}[X]<\infty$ (a counterexample would be instructive)? Or might anyone be able to suggest other additional conditions so that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\infty$?

Comment: Crossposted to MO (please don't do this): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94140/convergence-of-infinite-moments

Comment: For example you can have that $X=0$ a.s.. Try to construct a counterexample: start with a r.v. that is not integrable, and use the indicator function.

Comment: Re: crossposting
Thanks for the advice. Rest assured I didn't intend to violate written and unwritten rules of etiquette. I didn't see anything against crossposting in the FAQ so I didn't think much of it when I posted in both mathoverflow and stackexchange; I just wanted to reach a wider audience. 

I'll take this into account next time.

Comment: **Counterexample**: Let $Y \geq 0$ such that $\mathbb E Y = \infty$. Define $X_n = n^{-1} Y$.

Comment: No worries, Richard (or Charles?). Quasi-official policy on this is on the meta site, but it's hard to expect new users to know this. Consider the previous comments as a courtesy; welcome to the site! :)

Comment: Just to provide some context, I have $X_n \Rightarrow Z$, where all r.v.'s are non-degenerate (there is a density on an interval). Thus, $e^{X_n}\Rightarrow e^Z$ (continuous mapping thm). However, while all moments of $X_n$ & $Z$ are finite, $\mathbb{E}[e^{X_n}] = \infty$. I was hoping $\mathbb{E}[e^Z] = \infty$ too. Note that $e^Z$ is non-degenerate, and so it's a different mold from the counterexamples provided. If someone has a non-degenerate counterexample, it could give me an idea what to avoid so I could still perhaps hope to get my desired result. Thanks!

Comment: Two thoughts, which are a bit unlikely to be helpful (the information provided is still a little sparse). Define $T_n = \inf_{k \geq n} X_k$. Then, of course, if for some $n$ you can show that $\mathbb E e^{T_n} = \infty$, you'd be done. Second, it's not clear what you mean by "all moments of $X_n$ and $Z$ are finite". If by that you only meant that "for all $n$, $\mathbb E |X_n| < \infty$ and the same for $Z$", then if you can show that $\mathbb E X_n^k = \infty$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$ and all sufficiently large $n$, you'd also be done. :)

Comment: It is almost as easy to construct counterexamples that converge to any nondegenerate limit you wish. Let $Y \geq 0$ with $\mathbb E Y = \infty$ as before and let $Z$ have an *arbitrary* distribution. Then, take $X_n = (1-n^{-1}) Z + n^{-1} Y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n$ of density $f_n(x):=\frac{2n}{\pi(1+nx^2)}\chi_{(0,+\infty)}$; if $g$ is a continuous bounded function then 
$$\int_0^{+\infty}(f_n(x)g(x)-f_n(x)g(0))dx\leq 2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|g(tn^{-1})-g(0)|}{\pi(1+t^2)}dt$$
and by the dominated convergence theorem it converges to $0$. So $X_n$ converges in distribution to $\delta_0$ which have moments of each orders.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be this complicated. Any sequence that converges a.s. to zero but has infinite mean for all $n$ works.

Comment: @cardinal Indeed (at least, if the OP adds "continuous" we have an example).

Comment: Ah wonderful! The counterexamples are instructive, and cardinal's was really simple too.